# Django - urls.py REGEX

Tags: django, django-urls

I am having some trouble writing the regex portion of the url for a Django project.

I want to be able to route along with capturing a profile ID

URL Example: www.somesite.com/profile/12345678901

This is what I have so far

```
url(r'^profile/$', views.dashboard, name='widget')
```

Whats the correct REGEX that should go after the profile/?
How would I capture the numeric part after the profile/? once I am in the view?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<id>[\d]+)/$', profile_view, name="profile"),
```

and in the view

```
def profile_view(request, id):
    #some logic here...
```

Comment: +1. While this would work, i would recommend the [Named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) - Something like `url(r'^profile/(?P<id>[\d]+)/$', profile_view, name="profile"),` to keep things more explicit