# Pass value in a Template to a View in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, view, django-urls

maybe this is to easy but i'm having troubles.

I need to pass a value in a template.html to a view.py i've already search for this question in google and django docs however the only solution founded was to use: URL (GET) is there another form?

I have this in course_main.html:

```
{% for Course in Course %}
                <div id='courseContainer'>
                            <h4 class="center"> {{ Course.name }} </h4>
                            <a href="course/{{ Course.name }}"><img class="center" src="{{ Course.image.url }}"/></a>
                            <p class="center"> {{ Course.date }} </p>
                            <p> {{ Course.description }} </p>
                <!--End courseContainer -->
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So when a user press: <'img class="center" src="{{ Course.image.url }}"/> 
 this redirects to the variable in {{ Course.name }}

and this is handle by explicit_course in the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
#Courses
(r'^course/[a-z].*$',explicit_course),
```

)

Here is explicit_course views.py:

```
def explicit_course(request):
profesor = Professor.objects.get(id=1)
courseExplicit = Course.objects.get(name="django-python")
variables = RequestContext(request,{
    'CourseExplicit':courseExplicit,
    'Profesor':profesor
})
return  render_to_response('course_explicit.html',variables)
```

Here i want to do something like this:

```
courseExplicit = Course.objects.get(name="Course.name")
```

But i don't know how to pass the Course value from course_main.html to explicit_course in views.py

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, all you want to do is pass the value of the course name in the URL, and then you wish to look this up and display the results in your template?

Comment: First of all, `{% for Course in Course %}` would not work. Next, you already have access to the queryset object in the view. You need to pass the `id` through a URL and access it in the view

Comment: Duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635255/django-urls-py-regex/17635270#17635270

Comment: Yes i want to pass the value of Course.name into explicit_course that way i can do courseExplicit = Course.objects.get(name="Course.name") and render the proper views.  For example if a user hits ios course the path would be:   course/ios
if another hits django course the url would be
course/django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `urls.py` to use a named regex expression:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
#Courses
(r'^course/(?P<course_name>[a-z]+)$',explicit_course),
)
```

And then change your `explicit_course` view to say this:

```
def explicit_course(request, course_name):
    profesor = Professor.objects.get(id=1)
    courseExplicit = Course.objects.get(name=course_name)
    # etc...
```

Named regex matches in your `urls.py` will pass their contents as variables to the view (after `request`), which you can then use as normal.

You're not really 'passing value from template to view', you're just pulling data out of the URL.

Documentation can be found here, it's worth a read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#named-groups